# Oracle Query (Time)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was wondering if somebody could help me with this query. I am trying calculate the minutes for the "Hour" column so that way I can know how many minutes it took an operator to complete a task. If it possible also if there is a way to add all those minutes per User_ID and divide them by the sum of the cases picked and the sum of lines picked. I hope anybody can help me with this.

This is the query I currently have:

```
--Productivity "Cases/Lines Picked"
select trunc(dstamp) "DATE", user_id, to_char(dstamp, 'HH12') "HOUR", to_char(dstamp, 'AM') "AM/PM",
ROUND(sum(update_qty / substr(sku_id, instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1) +1 , instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 2) - 1 - instr(sku_id, '-', 1, 1)))) "CASES_PICKED",
COUNT(CODE) "Lines Picked"
from v_inventory_transaction 
where client_id = 'USKIDS2CA' 
and code = 'Pick' 
and list_id IS NOT NULL 
and STATION_ID LIKE 'R%' 
and reference_id not like '%-FK%' 
AND trunc(dstamp) = '03/21/2022'
group by trunc(dstamp), user_id, to_char(dstamp, 'HH12'), to_char(dstamp, 'AM')
ORDER BY 4;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkLHV.png)

Comment: Please post the table of v_inventory_transaction  + sample data as text. Thank you

Comment: Please read (and heed) about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You want the minutes needed for a task. How do you identify a task? And as you are showing hours, what if a task starts at 9:55 and ends at 10:20? That makes 25 minutes, but would you show it then for 9 am or 10 am? Or would you show 5 minutes for 9 am and 20 minutes for 10 am? Please edit your request and show us sample data and the expected result as formatted text (not as images). You shouldn't compare dates with strings by the way. Use date literals (e.g. `DATE '2022-03-21'` ). Otherwise your query can crash when session settings don't match the date format you use in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an DATE column there is no need to calculate the minutes you can extract them

```
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';


SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24') AS CURRENT_HOUR FROM DUAL;

SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MI') AS CURRENT_MIN FROM DUAL;
```